# ChannelSurfCli is not creating channels on Teams

Tags: slack, microsoft-teams

I was trying to create two channels in teams, i run the script and seems like the script run but it doesn´t create any channel and i didn´t recieve any error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fgLu.png)

Does anybody know about this?

thx in advance

Comment: Please post your question on ChannleSurf in [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/updated-teams-command-line-tool-channel-surf/m-p/106087) forum. 
You can use [Graph API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create new channels in bulk.